# Save changes within a button in android

Tags: android, button, save, state

i am new in android development, and i'm trying to figure out how cand i make a button to save changes in a Activity. Brief: i have a seekBar where i can change the ringer volume, but it changes directley for System, i put a Button to Save the changes, and i don't know how to do this. This is my code:

**main.xml**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekVolume"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Activity**

```
public class SaveActivity extends Activity {

    private AudioManager aManager;
    private SeekBar seekVolume;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        setOnClickListener();      
}
    private void setOnClickListener(){
        SeekBar seekVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekVolume);

        seekVolume.setMax(aManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
        seekVolume.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);
        seekVolume.setProgress(aManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
        seekVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar ringvolume) {
            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar ringvolume) {
            }
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar ringvolume, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
aManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, progress, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND); 
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
            seekVolume.setProgress(aManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
    }
        return (super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
    }

}
```

I really don't know how to do this. Thanks Guys!

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 you refeer to PreferenceActivity? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read your preferences (in `onCreate()`):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
seekVolume.setProgress(preferences.getInt("storedVol", 0));
```

To save your preferences (in `onDestroy()`):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreference(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedVol", seekVolume.getProgress()); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

You retrieve `Button save` in `onCreate()` but do nothing with it. What do you want it to do? How about connecting its `onClickListener` by adding

```
  save.setOnClickListener(mySaveHandler);
```

to `onCreate()`? Then:

```
View.OnClickListener mySaveHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // Save preferences here instead/aswell
 }
}
```

Comment: Thx very much, but i have a question: Where should i read my preference, in **onCreate** ? and where should i save it in **onKeyDown** or in my **setOnClickListener** method? Thx guys

Comment: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Et9oYakNinI/T58IH6ifOYI/AAAAAAAAAIg/u_N08o-g-eg/s1600/c0043363_49336ea62d4c6.jpg

Comment: Thanx, but where should i put the `save.setOnClickListener` ? I understand that when i press the **save** button, then the changes is saved within SharedPreferences. Sorry for my persistance but i am new, and try to understand :)

Comment: if i put the code above, My App changes the ringtone volume (as in my initial code), instead of that, Save button is unused, and when i press the Back Button from Phone, My App get Crash...Please mate